# Java Nullpointexception when creating a text file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use the functions i made in this class at the main but it crashes and says "WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0
x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
whenever i try to do grabar.touchFile();

Here is the class i made: http://pastebin.com/eNWrp07f

```
package com.brackeen.javagamebook.grabar;

import java.io.*;

public class Grabar{
    private int mapaTexto;
    private String nombreArchivo = "Grabar.txt";

    public void touchFile() throws IOException{
        File f = new File(nombreArchivo);
        if (!f.isFile())
            f.createNewFile();
    }

    public int readFile() throws IOException{
        try{
            touchFile();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nombreArchivo));
        String dato = fileIn.readLine();
        int mapaTexto = Integer.parseInt(dato);
        fileIn.close();
        return mapaTexto;
    }

    public void writeFile(int n) throws IOException{
        try{
            touchFile();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(nombreArchivo));
        fileOut.println(n);
        fileOut.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the NullPointerException?  It's difficult to help you without the actual error message.

Comment: Note that if the file `Grabar.txt` is not present, then it'd create a new file and that will throw a `NumberFormatException` @ this line `int mapaTexto = Integer.parseInt(dato);`.

Comment: Also note that if this directory structure is not present, `com/brackeen/javagamebook` it'd **NOT CREATE** any missing folder in that structure and hence will throw an `IOException` @ `f.createNewFile();`. Thus both scenarios will throw exceptions!

Comment: I've edited the post with the exception.
Here is the main http://pastebin.com/VvBPdyS6 i use this class in line 92 and 531. the directory is present but to make sure i tried it just using "Grabar.txt" that didn't work either same exception. I tried doing the touchFile() in every read write to make sure it's there but i still get the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your pastebin dump, the issue isn't with your `Grabar` class, but with your `init()` function of your `GameManager` class.  You are attempting to call `touchFile()` on your `Grabar` instance but you have not yet created one with the `new` operator.

Add this line somewhere before the `touchFile()` method in your `init()` method:

```
grabar = new Grabar();
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much! I can't believe it was something so silly!